# why do these sounds make a dog unhappy?

Tags: zoology

[Cross-posted from StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49350225/why-do-these-sounds-make-a-dog-unhappy)

This is an odd one. I'm not sure it's the right place to ask, but maybe there are some sound / dog experts who can chime in? (no pun intended)

We use [two sounds](https://soundcloud.com/user-919494216/sets/alfie-take-2) on our website to indicate success and failure on a quiz. Those are very simple and short sounds.

Somehow one of our customers reported that her dog was whimpering and really upset with both of those sounds. He's normally fine with lots of other sounds that dogs are typically unhappy with including loud sounds, hoovers etc. She even said it happens when she uses headphones!

Other than muting, or replacing those sounds (and upsetting other dogs?), is there anything we can do to clean the sound or detect what specifically makes them upset this or other dogs?

Comment: Just a note:  I'd recommend deleting the cross-post on SO.  Of course, it will automatically get deleted in a while, but as a general rule, it's better to keep questions on a single site.  Welcome to the site!

Comment: Thanks @rotaredom. Good to be here :) I'm still not entirely sure where it fits best... I'm pretty sure it would require some cross-domain knowledge (computer/sound processing, and understanding of animal physiology).

Comment: I get a message that "questions with open bounties cannot be deleted", so I am currently unable to delete it...

Comment: I just played the sounds on loud with my three dogs, all within a ~3 feet of me (they're sheepherding breeds, so they stay close to their human.) Not a one had a reaction, though I tried several times. My youngest dog, though, a Belgian Tervuren, is very sensitive to sound, and whimpers when I play the live version of Jeff Buckley's "Hallelujah" in the car. Not the regular version, mind you, just the live version, which is much more tender (as if that's possible.) So, my guess is that your main assumption is wrong. One dog only.

Comment: P.S. I love your pun!

Comment: Thanks for willing to experiment on your three dogs, @anongoodnurse. I thought about doing it, but I don't have a dog, and wasn't so comfortable trying out something weird on strangers' dogs. That's already very useful. At least it's good to know that it's not a widespread issue... at least with the current sample of 1 out of 4, ;-)